# Kendo-Grid Angular UI trackby

Tags: performance, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-angular-ui

In Angulars `ngFor` you can use `trackBy` to pass a key so that Angular doesn't reload everything but only the items really needed.

Does the kendo-grid also function that way and if not by default, is it possible to pass a key to it, too?

Comment: Just FYI: If you own a commercial-license you do have access to the [Source Code](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/source-code/).

Comment: @Philipp Sadly I‘ve only access to the minified version currently in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the documentation link: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-trackby

A quick example would be something like this:

```
<!-- template -->
<kendo-grid 
    [kendoGridBinding]="taskData"
    [trackBy]="trackById">

trackById(index: number, item: GridItem) {
  const dataItem = item.data as TaskItem;
  return dataItem.id;
}
```